# Show data from DB, smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

im Smarty newbee. Trying to show some data from Database, but nothing display in browser page. I tried to show the query in php file, all works fine, but i cant display in Smarty. My code here:
New.php

```
<?php
include 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
$link = mysqli_connect ('localhost','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `s_news`";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[] = $row; # $data is the array created for use in the Smarty template. 
$smarty->assign('data', $data); 
$smarty->display('text.tpl'); 
}
?>
```

Text.tpl file:

```
{foreach from=$cat1 item=item}
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
<td>Username:</td> 
</tr> 
{foreach from=$data item=item key=key} 
<tr> 
<td>{$item.date}</td> 
<tr> 
{/foreach} 
</table> 
{/foreach}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should assign outside the loop

Comment: @YourCommonSense pls answer. I cant imagine what you said.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning and trying to display the template inside the while loop. Do it outside, after all the data has been collected

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$data[] = $row; # $data is the array created for use in the Smarty template. 
}
$smarty->assign('data', $data); 
$smarty->display('text.tpl');
```

Comment: , not working, mb i must include some other libs? How do you think?

Comment: If that's all your code, then you should also initialize $smarty with $smarty = new Smarty(). Please, take a look at the manual: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl

Comment: now  i make, follow your instructions. Trying var_dump of mysqli query, i get info, but i think mistake in text.tpl file. Check please, text.tpl correct? Name of columns to show are 'date' and 'news'

Comment: the tpl seems to be correct, problem must be that is trying to loop through an undefined variable: $cat1. Are you really sure of what are you doing and trying to archieve?

Comment: [code] <TR> 
          <TD>{$data.news}</TD> 
        
        </TR> 
       [/code], but again nothing.